# How to make sure SQLite never create a row with the same ID twice?

Tags: sqlite, uniqueidentifier

I have a SQLite table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Cards (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT)
```

So each time I create a new row, SQLite is going to automatically assign it a unique ID.

However, if I delete a row and then create a new row, the new row is going to have the ID of the previously deleted row.

How can I make sure it doesn't happen? Is it possible to somehow force SQLite to always give really unique IDs, that are even different from previously deleted rows?

I can do it in code but I'd rather let SQLite do it if it's possible. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [autoincrement](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) (INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT).  It will guarantee this and if the request can't be honored it will fail with SQLITE_FULL.